# Is it possible to pass/use an existing (instantiated) class in multiple job worker classes?

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to pass/use a class that was instantiated before dispathcing the jobs and pass into multiple jobs?

```
public function fetchOrders(){
    $platform = new App\Adapters\platform;

    foreach($orders as $order){     
        App\Jobs\FechThemJob::dispatch($platform, $order);
    }
}
```

Will such a process work and will it keep all the class (initialized) properties ?

Comment: I did not understand what you asked.

Comment: Why would you want to do something with a job after it was dispatched? Possible XY problem?

Comment: @GiacomoM Lets say I have instantiated a platform class which has a counter propery 0. After instantiating that class I pass it into a loop where jobs will be dispatched using this class. And each job increases that class's counter property.

Comment: @Jerodev actaually I need to make a lot of calls to an api and store the returned result in db. And I want to use jobs for this in order to be faster using asyn process. Here each job will connect to the api and store the result but it will (should) continue the remaining page of the results which is stored in the $platform class.

Comment: this doc can help you I guess https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: You could store the counter in the database and retrieve it during each job. That way you don't have a dependency on your platform anymore.

Comment: @PtrTon the class had other properties as control static methods as well. So this is not possible I think. Actually I instatniated and set up all the needed options before the job dispatch and put the other (that needed to be async) inside the job. Now its working as I need.